# Convert string to integer pandas dataframe index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a multiindex. Unfortunately one of the indices gives years as a string

e.g. '2010', '2011'

how do I convert these to integers?

More concretely

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'2010', u'2011'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
 10, 11, 12, , ...]], names=[u'Year', u'Month'])
```

.

```
df_cbs_prelim_total.index.set_levels(df_cbs_prelim_total.index.get_level_values(0).astype('int'))
```

seems to do it, but not inplace. Any proper way of changing them?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: can you just convert them before assigning them to your index? that would seem to be the least painful method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will probably be cleaner to do this before you assign it as index (as @EdChum points out), but when you already have it as index, you can indeed use `set_levels` to alter one of the labels of a level of your multi-index. A bit cleaner as your code (you can use `index.levels[..]`):

```
In [165]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3], ['2011','2012','2013']])

In [166]: idx
Out[166]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3], [u'2011', u'2012', u'2013']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

In [167]: idx.levels[1]
Out[167]: Index([u'2011', u'2012', u'2013'], dtype='object')    

In [168]: idx = idx.set_levels(idx.levels[1].astype(int), level=1)

In [169]: idx
Out[169]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3], [2011, 2012, 2013]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

You have to reassign it to save the changes (as is done above, in your case this would be `df_cbs_prelim_total.index = df_cbs_prelim_total.index.set_levels(...)`)

Comment: Note that the `levels` method of a pandas MultiIndex seems to sort the individual levels *lexicographically* (even if these are of int type). This may reorder the index labels for a given level without maintaining the MultiIndex tuples (e.g., if you have indices 1-100, these will be reordered as 1,10,100,2,20,3..., independently of other levels). In this case one should explicitly sort the converted index within `set_levels()`.

In the example above (input cell [168]):
`idx = idx.set_levels(idx.levels[1].astype(int).sort_values(), level=1)`.